# Chartjs removing labels and begin number

Tags: d3.js, chart.js

This is my my current code:

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    
    data: {
        labels: [.some label.],
        datasets: [{
            // label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [.some color.],
            borderColor: ['some color'],
            borderWidth: 0,
            barPercentage:1,
            categoryPercentage:0.8,
            maxBarThickness: 30,
        }]
    },
    options: {
        legend: {
            display: false,
        },
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        },
    }
});
```

I am trying to delete these two labels and begin number. Also i wan to keep the whole background white but it has some line, which i dont want.
Can anyone help in this case?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use display property of gridLines for X and Y axis to remove the checkered grid so that background would be white.

```
xAxes: [{
          gridLines: {
            display: false
        }
       }],
 yAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },  
       ....
       ....
```

for removing the X and Y axis labels you should set display property of ticks to false

```
 yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
                display: false
            }
      }]
```

please have a look at code snippet.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
        ticks: {
          display: false
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
        ticks: {
          display: false
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```